# Autocompletar campo de texto jquery desde mysql (usar el mismo campo varias veces para añadir más opciones)

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

No tengo mucha idea de jquery. Necesito hacer un campo de texto autocompletable, que busque lo que tengo en la base de datos, esa parte la tengo cubierta más o menos con este código de aquí:
http://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

Pero lo que necesito es algo más complejo y no sé ni por donde empezarlo.

Al introducir unas letras o palabras en el area de texto me salen las que coinciden parcialmente, o totalmente, pero quiero en cuando lo haga click en una de las "sugerencias" los datos de ésta se metan en un array (el id, precio, nombre de un item, por ejemplo) y que aparezca reflejado de algún modo en el código html, es decir que sea visual para el usuario final. Después de seleccionar uno de los items de la tabla, necesito que el campo de texto usado antes para buscar se "resetee" y se pued volver a usar del mismo modo, es decir buscar otra palabra y al hacer click ésta sea añadida al array, para guardar esos datos y enviarlos en un formulario.

No sé si me he explicado correctamente y se aceptan sugerencias para cambiar la pregunta o el título ya que no sé como describir correctamente lo que estoy buscando...

Gracias.

EDITO:

En un principio no se sabe cuantos items se van a seleccionar, tanto puede ser 1 como pueden ser 20.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece por lo se ve en el ejemplo del link que pusiste, que estas usando el autocomplete de Jquery. De manera que encontre el siguiente enlace con un ejemplo que encaja con tu solicitud:

[Ejemplo de Jquery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)

Para que funcione necesitas dos partes, el ejemplo que tu pones te dice como sacar los datos desde la base de MySQL, de manera que en lugar del objeto que trae el ejemplo del sitio de JQuery, la variable de Javascript `projects`

```
var projects = [
  {
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
    icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
  }
];
```

Esto habría que borrarlo y reemplazar por lo que traes de la base de datos.

De manera que habria que cambiar el código de ejemplo que tu pones, para que cuando se haga el JSON Encode, traiga dentro de si, los objetos con toda la info que tu quieras, te pongo un ejemplo de como podría ser:

```
//get matched data from skills table
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM skills WHERE skill LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY skill ASC");
$i = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$i]['id']     = $row['id'];
    $data[$i]['image']  = $row['image'];
    $data[$i]['name']   = $row['name'];
    $data[$i]['value']  = $row['value'];
    $i++;
}

//return json data
echo json_encode($data);
```

Al hacer el `json_encode` verás que ya toma una forma mas parecida al array de javascript `projects` del ejemplo la página de JQuery que te puse.

Edición: Para hacer que pase los datos de la selección a otra página de PHP puedes hacer varias cosas, en el ejemplo del link que puse anteriormente:

```
 select: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label ); //Como puedes ver en el objeto ui.item vienen los valores que vienen del JSON que mando el php que se creo anteriormente. En este caso #project podría ser el objeto hidden
    $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
    $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
    $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

    return false;
```

En este caso, como lo menciona el siguiente artículo de [Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29076298/4598488), puedes hacer un solo elemento tipo `<input type ="hidden">` sobre el cual usando `JSON.stringify` se convierte en otro objeto JSON que facilmente podes manipular al enviar a tu página target PHP.

El script completo debe quedar algo así:

```
 <script>
$( function() {


$( "#project" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: paginaFuente.php,
  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
     //GENERAR UN SOLO ARRAY, CON LOS VALORES QUE VIENEN DE LA BASE DE DATOS
    var elems = [];
    elems.push(ui.item.label);
    elems.push(ui.item.value);
    elems.push(ui.item.picsrc);

    //GUARDAR EN CAMPO HIDDEN TODO; HECHO JSON usando JSON.stringify
    $('#input_hidden_field').val(JSON.stringify(elems)); //store array

    var value = $('#input_hidden_field').val(); //retrieve array
    value = JSON.parse(value);

    return false;
  }
})
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<div>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
} );
</script>

//LUEGO EN ALGUNA PARTE DEL BODY
<form id="test"  action="otherPhpPage.php">
<input type="hidden" id="input_hidden_field" value="" />
</form>
```

Espero que esto responda a tu pregunta.

Comment: Y como puedo hacer para que cuando, por ejemplo yo cojo dos "objetos" de la tabla items, como puedo con jquery enviar a mi código php la cantidad de items que he escogido y mandarlo a una variable o array de php? Siento preguntar tanto pero es que todo esto de `json` no tendgo ni idea de como funciona. Es decir Primero hago select de mi tabla, lo meto en la variable data como pones en tu código. Pero por que está comentado el rleturn json data que es lo que hace el echo del final? Como trabajo esas variables en jquery, y como las envio de vuelta al php? Gracias.

Comment: Para enviarlos de regreso a PHP es fácil: tienen que ir en un `<form>` para que pueda enviarse a una página destino, para esto, dentro de la función del Javascript donde esta el autocompletar, tienes que hacer que tome cada variable que viene en el objeto y se escriba en un tag `<hidden>` esto lo tendrías que hacer en la porción de código que te envié de ejemplo. Editare mi respuesta para poner esto.

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta. puedes revisar @PavloB.

Comment: De qué manera se puede abrir un chat privado para consultarte algunas dudas?

Comment: hola @PavloB. dame un correo y te escribo o tu usuario de Skype. Saludos!

Comment: pavlobod91@gmail.com